# Base keyword for inherting from a class

Tags: c#, keyword, radix, base-class

```
public FileSearch1a(string lookIn, string fileSpec, bool searhSubFolders) : base(lookIn, fileSpec, searhSubFolders)
{
    // Call the base class constructor.
}
```

In c#; Am I right to say, here I am calling base class constructor with its named parameters (not changing names of params but I can if I wanted to by changing first parameters' name) and in constructor body, I am letting base classes constructor content to run (I can overload it if I wanted to)?

Comment: You should specify what language this is.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with named parameters. If you called it using constants, you would still be invoking the base class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This will ensure the base class constructor has been executed, with the relevant overload if applicable matching the parameters that you are supplying.

Note you can also use `this` to invoke another constructor in the same class with matching parameters (called chaining constructors)

```
public FileSearch1a(string lookIn, string fileSpec) : this(lookIn, fileSpec, false)
{
    // Call the base class constructor.
}
```

Comment: that comment is a bit misleading. You don't call the base class constructor in the block of the derived constructor. The base constructor has already been called when entering that block.

Comment: 1. Why am I declaring parameters types in first parenthesises? 2.Is this called constructor overloading? And with empty body, no overloading here? 3.Can I add more parameters as long as I provide base constructor parameters and dome more work with my own parameters in body?

Comment: Calling the same constructor with the same parameters will lead to a stack overflow. You meant to be calling another constructor in the same class with _different_ parameters, surely?

Comment: I am just trying to understand how this call works and what is capabilities of it? I mean different versions.

Comment: Ozgur: Would be worth you doing some more research by the sound of it. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx

Comment: I know what Constructors and base keyword means and do here.  I am trying to understand the syntax. But I guess, I should read more articles. Then maybe I can ask the question in right way :)